# Space before paragraph with bulleted lists in tables

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table of three cells, each cell containing a **separate** bulleted list. My "Normal" style is formatted with an 18pt space before the paragraph. However, in this table, the 18pt space is only being honoured in the first cell. The subsequent cells appear to be treated as continuations of the first list. I have already tried "Separate List" from the context menu but no luck.

Screenshot below, showing a sample table and the styles dialog.

Any thoughts on how to get Word to honour the paragraph spacing in all three cells?

Word version is 2016 on Windows 10.

[image: Screenshot showing table and style dialog]

Comment: I think you may have formatted the area of which the table lives which will include everything in the table because it's part of the area. Tables might behave in a "wrap around" affect too which is why it's affecting the apparent 3 cells, but might be acting as 3 columns? Might try scrapping the cells for now. Write it out and style it, then wrap them in a cell afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPTION #1:  Add a non-bulleted paragraph at the end of the bullet list in in each cell.  That seems to "separate" the lists and you'll get the space at the top of the next cell.

OPTION #2:  If your cells are only going to contain the bulleted lists, you could workaround the issue by removing the space before on your Normal style, and instead modify the cell margins for the table so the top margin is 18pt.

Comment: Option #1 works, and would be the simplest answer, but ended up going for Option #2 because I don't have non-bulleted paragraphs in the cell content.